# Can't access Environment Variables Remote Server Django

Tags: python, django

On my remote server, running Ubuntu 14.04, with server configuration: Django, Nginx and Gunicorn, I can't access environment variables although set under the right user and server restarted.

On my local box, I set the environment variables, and django can access during startup and works nicely. On the remote server, although the environment variables are in place, django complains of keyerror.

```
# from two scoops

import os
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

def get_env_variable(var_name):
    """Get the environment variable or return exception"""
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the {} environment variable".format(var_name)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
```

On the server, the user running the django instance is the same user in which the environment variables were set to.

Everything works on the local PC. On the remote machine, it doesn't. I've restarted the server, still.

When I run `export` in terminal on the remote server, I get the list of environment variables including what I customly set.

To confirm, i went into python to verify.

```
import os
os.environ['THE_CUSTOM_KEY']
>> returns the Key
```

If Django **is** Python, then what step am I missing, because python sees the environment variables?

**Edit**: I set the variables in the `~/.profile` file of the user account.

My ~/.profile with the variables

```
# top part cut for brevity
export LOG_ECG_DB="name"
export LOG_ECG_EMAIL="email@gmail.com"
export LOG_ECG_EMAIL_PW="password"
export LOG_ECG_PW="password"
export LOG_ECG_SECRET="secret_key"
```

Comment: `Django` is not `Python`, its a `Web Framework` written in Python (Remember this for interview question) :)

Comment: How are you setting these variables? Where?

Comment: My *is* expression there was to mean, Django *is written* in Python. @AamirAdnan Therefore if python sees it, why is the framework ON the python not seeing it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added the vars to the `~/.profile` file in the user. Updated question to include that.

Comment: And what user is gunicorn running under? How are you starting it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Gunicorn runs under name, 'django' (that's the user).  All the project files are located, and run also under 'django' user home directory. However, even before allowing Gunicorn to take over, I run `python manage.py runserver' in the root folder of the project to verify if all will go well. That fails too. I tried the gunicorn too, fails.

Comment: How is the gunicorn/django server being started? If you start it from the shell yourself, then the behaviour would be strange. But if it's started from e.g. a crontab/supervisord-script, then this doesn't know anything about .profile etc. These are for shells & user logins. Just because a process is launched under a certain user doesn't mean it will inherit the shell env.

Comment: @deets  How strange if I start from the shell? Doing so locally doesn't face any errors. On remote, keyerror. What difference is it in my local terminal and remote terminal? Besides, both remote and local, the env vars are added to ~/.profile, and when run `export`, my custom env vars show. I'm running a gunicorn.conf from /etc/init/ on startup.

Comment: You still didn't answer the question how the server is started. You mention nginx- so how's the django app launched? Via cgi ?

Comment: @deets A conf file in /etc/init/ which starts on system startup into a service. I hope that answers how I start the server.

Comment: Well, and does that config file set the env vars? If not -again - the .profile doesn't matter. That is only relevant for you ssh-ing into the system. The init.d script is started by root & then just changes the user. No login, no bash, no profile or bashrc or whatever.

Comment: Sure @deets I think I get your point now. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87664/discussion-between-rexford-and-deets).

Comment: I can't chat. I don't think nginx is the issue. It's different process. Unless nginx is responsible starting the process (which it seems not to), all you can & need to do is to set the vars in the init script.

Comment: @deets Thanks for the tips. Will update how it goes.

Comment: @deets figured it out and working in production now. Posted my how-to below. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, below is how I solved the issue. Might help someone. Inspired by example in two scoops

Steps in brief:

- Created a json file in ~/.env
- Lets settings.py read the json file upon load
- Keys from the file are used to fill in the sensitive parts

### created json file

I put the file in ~/.env of both my local and remote machine, with the content

```
{
"SECRET_KEY": "my_secret_key",
"DB": "db_name",
"USER": "db_user",
"USER_PW": "db_user_password",

"EMAIL": "email@email.com",
"EMAIL_PW": "password"
}
```

If your app isn't sending any emails, you might not need the last two lines in the above snippet

### Read json

In my settings.py (or you could put into a utils.py file, whatever), I have this snippet:

```
import json
from os.path import expanduser
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

# with this, no need to hardcode
# home directory
home_directory = expanduser("~")

with open(home_directory + "/.env") as f:
    secrets = json.loads(f.read())


def get_secret(setting, secrets=secrets):
    """Get the secret variable or return explicit exception."""
    try:
        return secrets[setting]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the {0} environment variable".format(setting)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
```

### Fill in the pieces

Like so `SECRET_KEY = get_secret('SECRET_KEY')`

and so on..

Answer (score -2):

This is an NGINX "issue".  When NGINX starts, it wipes all environment variables besides timezone.  You can manually set environment variables using an NGINX configuration file.  But of course then the data will be in plaintext in that configuration file.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env

Comment: I don't see this helping, because on my local PC, I don't use nginx to serve the development server, plus, switching to DEBUG=False with production settings, the server runs without any error (except statics aren't loaded). Thus, this isn't anywhere close to NGINX, I think. My problem is way past the part Nginx plays in the request chain. The problem is currently happening *after* nginx sends incoming request to django for processing. Getting Nginx to pass env variables to django? I doubt I wanna do that.

Comment: on your local machine, are you serving via NGINX or via django's development server?

Comment: Any chance you could respond to my question here?  Are you serving via NGINX locally?  I ask because when you serve via the development server (typical, for local testing) then environment variables set for the current user are available to Python/Django.  However, when things are run via the NGNIX server (which is itself run by the root user) NGINX explicitly strips away all environment variables for the relevant python processes.  I.e. it would explain the issues you're having...

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I was using local Django development server.

Comment: Ok.  I'm not sure if you downvoted me here, but for what its worth, I believe I actually pointed you in the right direction.  In your remote (production/NGINX) configuration, the NGINX process was stripping away your environment variables.  On your local (development/devserver) configuration, no such stripping was happening.  Therefore all local environment variables were "in effect" but all remote ones were "unavailable".  Hence the same code throwing errors remotely (missing keys) but working correctly locally.  Your workaround, is, of course, valid.  But I believe my diagnosis was accurate.